# 複数のオブジェクトの取得

Tags: c#, unity3d

既にinstantiateで生成された複数のobjを
Findで取得し、positionをrandom.rangeで移動させ
取得したオブジェクトは個々をRandom.Rangeで移動させたいのですが

下記で実装したところ、　取得したオブジェクトはRandom.Rangeで移動することは
できたのですが、一箇所に固まってしまいます。
複数のobjを別々に移動させる方法はありますでしょうか

```
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    x = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);
    y = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);
    z = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);


    aa= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("obj");
    foreach (GameObject tt in aa)

    tt.transform.position=new Vector3(x,y,z);
```

Answer (score 4):

現状の実装だと、
・ランダム設定した位置情報を、オブジェクト200個に設定
となっていますので、
・オブジェクト200個それぞれに、ランダム設定した位置情報を設定
とすれば、よいかと思います。

```
float x,y,z;
aa= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("obj");
foreach (GameObject tt in aa){
    x = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);
    y = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);
    z = Random.Range (-200.0f, 200.0f);

    tt.transform.position=new Vector3(x,y,z);
}
```